# CSRF token implimentation on different views in web application issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csrf-protection

Different views generating different token. But we can access the different action with different valid tokens in the same session. What is this issue?

Comment: Tell us more about what you have done already. Provide code!

Comment: In our application,added the   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  on  all views and added the  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] on post actions.we are using ajax posting.Now  different tokens are generated for different views . and the token is passed through the ajax data part.  On editing the request of  one page eg: "Customer delete" action  with  a token   of contract page post  in same session,customer delete takes place.we want to show the antiforgery error.How can we do this?